# XSL For-Each exclusion by ID

Tags: xslt

I've got an XSL issue.
With the following code I exclude Box1

```
<xsl:for-each select="//box[@id!='box1']">
```

But I also want to exclude Box7.
Is that possible and how can I do that?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two one-liner XPath solutions, the second showing how to easily exclude many nodes. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can AND those predicates together:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//box[@id!='box1'][@id!='box7']">
```

Comment: In this case, the same attribute, I would use the `and` operator.

Comment: @Alejandro: I'm partial to using multiple predicates, it just looks more clear to me. It would be nice if there were any coding standards regarding this (and xsl in general) :)

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
//box[not(@id='box1') and not(@id='box2')]
```

If you have many ids to exclude, use (in this example I am excluding "box1" - "box4"):

```
//box[not(contains('|box1|box2|box3|box4|', concat('|', @id, '|'))]
```

Comment: @Dimitre: For this case, where there can't be more than one `@id` attribute selected, the `!=` operator is enough. It might not be the case in other scenario, of course.

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, I know. And Yes, I do recommend not to use `!=` even in this case -- never use `!=` (maybe only in exceptional cases it may give you some expressional advantage) and thus never have nasty problems.

Comment: @Dimitre: Can you explain further why you never use `!=`?

Comment: @Alejandro: well, the intuitive expression (@id!=('box1','box7')) is certainly wrong - it's true if @id is ne box1 or ne box7, so it's always true.

Comment: @lwburk: If you have a variable `$nums` containing a nodeset: `<num>1</num><num>2</num><num>3</num>` and you compare `'1' != $nums`, the result is `true()`. The result of comparing `'1' = $nums` is also `true()`. This is the anomaly that people need to avoid. It is very embarassing to find this fact when debugging your code.

Comment: Attributes are unique for element. So, the main difference between this `@id!='box1' and @id!='box2'` and `not(@id='box1') and not(@id='box2')` is the way that they treat elements **without @id**. The first one won't select elements without `@id`, and the second one will select them.